# WebStorm 7.0.3 won't display a tree view for my project files

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with WebStorm for a few months. First time opening it and I run into an issue navigating the files in my project. It's incredibly annoying to not have a simple overview.

TL;DR: My editor refuses to show a tree view of my files.

None of the buttons seem to enable me to switch to a tree view, and I've perused the settings carefully and didn't find it, either.

I simply want to be able to browse my project with a tree view of folders and files. I've had it before, and for some reason it's gone.

How do I get a full tree view of folders and files back?

[image: Current view of my project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, restart) - does it help? BTW, do you have your source files stored locally, or on a remote drive? Are there any symlinks in your project path?

Comment: Invalidating the caches worked! No idea why, though. Source files are stored on my hard drive. With a git repository on a local network. No relevant symlinks that I'm aware of.